# Why such strange separation of variables?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, quantum-mechanics

In [this article](http://arxiv.org/abs/physics/9905051v1) the authors give the following expansion of wavefunction of three-body system (equation $(16)$ in text):

$$\Psi(\textbf{x},\textbf{y})=\sum_{q=\lambda}^l\psi_q(\textbf x^2,\textbf y^2,\textbf x\cdot\textbf y)Q_q(\textbf{x},\textbf{y}),$$

where $\textbf x$ and $\textbf y$ are scaled Jacobi coordinates (the third one is removed as center of mass position), $Q_q(\textbf{x},\textbf{y})$ are the eigenfunctions of $\hat L^2$, $\hat L_z$ and some other momentum-related operators (these functions are related to [Wigner D-matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_D-matrix), but expressed in non-angular coordinates), and $\psi_q(\textbf x^2,\textbf y^2,\textbf x\cdot\textbf y)$ are functions of the scalar coordinates, i.e. independent of system orientation.

What I don't understand is: why is it necessary to use the sum of products of angular-dependent functions with angular-independent ones, and not just *one* product as the solution? As I know from two-body problem, there one separates [spherical harmonics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics) from the radial function, and doesn't do any sum over harmonics with the same $l$, for example. Also, for the case of three *two-dimensional* particles there's no such feature, because the total angular momentum has only one dimension in this case. What's different here?

Are there any examples of PDEs where the solution needed a similar non-trivial separation of variables, but there were fewer dimensions, so that it could be visualized more easily?